# What is the maximum number of characters in a service name?

Tags: tcp, udp

In TCP/IP, a service name (like http or smtp) is an alias name for the port number. What is the maximum number of characters that can be used in a service name?

Comment: Does it matter which OS?

Comment: Well let's say linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to RFC 6335, the maximum length for a service name is 15 characters:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6335#section-5.1